# Put string content into array php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this string

```
string(2091) "


"roots" => array(
    array(
        "driver"        => "LocalFileSystem",   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
        "path"          => "../files/",         // path to files (REQUIRED)
        //"URL"           => dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "/../files/", // URL to files (REQUIRED)
        "accessControl" => "access" ,            // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        "alias" => "Root",
        //"uploadDeny"    => array("all"),
        "attributes" => array(
    array(
        "pattern" => "/\manuali$/",  //You can also set permissions for file types by adding, for example, <b>.jpg</b> inside pattern.
       // "pattern" =>"/\PROVA$/",
        "read" => true,
        "write" => false,
        "locked" => true,
    ),
    array(
        "pattern" => "/rapporti$/",  //You can also set permissions for file types by adding, for example, <b>.jpg</b> inside pattern.
       // "pattern" =>"/\PROVA$/",
        "read" => true,
        "write" => true,
        "locked" => true,
    )
     [...]
     ";
```

i want to put into array the entire value of a string. Ex:

```
array(


"roots" => array(
    array(
        "driver"        => "LocalFileSystem",   // driver for accessing file system (REQUIRED)
        "path"          => "../files/",         // path to files (REQUIRED)
        //"URL"           => dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "/../files/", // URL to files (REQUIRED)
        "accessControl" => "access" ,            // disable and hide dot starting files (OPTIONAL)
        "alias" => "Root",
        //"uploadDeny"    => array("all"),
        "attributes" => array(
    array(
        "pattern" => "/\manuali$/",  //You can also set permissions for file types by adding, for example, <b>.jpg</b> inside pattern.
       // "pattern" =>"/\PROVA$/",
        "read" => true,
        "write" => false,
        "locked" => true,
    ),
    array(
        "pattern" => "/rapporti$/",  //You can also set permissions for file types by adding, for example, <b>.jpg</b> inside pattern.
       // "pattern" =>"/\PROVA$/",
        "read" => true,
        "write" => true,
        "locked" => true,
    )
     [...]
     );
```

i have tried `str_split() implode() array_push()`... but every function put the string into array in this mode `array(string(" "))`i want to put in this mode `array(" ")`.

Thanks

Comment: What is producing that string in the first place? Can't you just serialize it instead of just printing it as a string and then trying to parse a string back into a complex structure

Comment: the string are a reading from a file ex. $xx=file_get_contents('out.txt');

Comment: The question still stands what is generating that string in that file. It would make more sense for that file to just contain the serialized structure rather than a string.

Comment: Stab in the dark here, but could `require` or `include` not work if it's in a separate file? Would need to prepend an open php tag and variable assignment, and then append a close php tag on to it though..

However, I guess this is just the same as `eval`ling it, not really the best idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is parseable and you don't mind about possible injections, you can simply [`eval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) your array representation.

For example, if your string is in `$arrayStr` and you want to create an array `$myArray` from that:

```
$arrayStr = '"roots" => array ( ... )';
eval('$myArray = array(' . $arrayStr . ');');
```

Note that if `$arrayStr` is not entirely controller by **you** from generation to conversion, it is **highly risky** since anything in it would be evaluated.

A better solution to exchange a whole array between parts of your application would be to [`serialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it beforehand to create a string representation of your array/object which can be stored, and then unserialize it when you need it in its original form.

Comment: can you explain me how works (in this case) the serialize() function?

Answer (score 1):

There's two main methods I can think of.

One, is to use some sort of complex pattern matching loop using `preg_match`. You can split the string into each line by using `explode` and `\n` to convert it into an array (of each line), loop through each row, and use pattern matching (regex) to figure out what to do with it.

The second method is incredibly dangerous, so I highly advise you to not use it, but php has it's own `eval` function which would let PHP interpret the string as actual PHP.

You would need to append a variable assignment inside the string e.g.

```
$arrayString = "$var = array(' . $arrayString . ');";
```

And then

```
eval($arrayString);
```

However, you really don't want to be doing this if you can. From the PHP docs:

> Caution
>
> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows
>   execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you
>   have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this
>   construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data
>   into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Comment: your solution generate string()= array(.. is the same of the other function, this is my problem.. the eval not work fine.. but thank you so much!